# including itensor library in my cmake project in clion

Tags: cmake, clion

so I am very new to CLion and CMake, so sorry in advance for wrong usage of terminology. I am suffering the following problem:

In my project I want to include the [ITensor library](https://github.com/ITensor/ITensor)   which is essentially a non-CMake project. I cloned the git to my computer and build the ITensor project. Next I wanted to use it in another project linking against it with CMake:

My Code in **main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "itensor.h"

int main() {
    std::string some_string = "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

and my **CMakeLists.txt** looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(tutorial)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")


set(ITENSOR_DIR PATH/TO/ITENSOR)
include_directories(ITENSOR_DIR/itensor)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        main.cpp
        ${ITENSOR_DIR}/itensor/itensor.h
        ${ITENSOR_DIR}/itensor/itensor.cc)

add_executable(tutorial ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Unfortunately, the project 'tutorial' does not build in CLion. Likewise, CLion cannot resolve the dependency itensor.h.
Anybody an Idea for why this is, respectively how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After trying Thomas5631's solution the compilation ran into linking issues with lapack. I solved this by adding some flags, though I'm not sure if all of them are required.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(my_project)
#Bring the headers into the project (full or relative path)
include_directories(itensor) 

#Link the Itensor library
add_library(itensor STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET itensor PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/david/my_project/itensor/lib/libitensor.a)

#Set a variable with all the new flags
set(ITENSOR_FLAGS "-DPLATFORM_lapack -D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0")
set(ITENSOR_LINK_FLAGS "-DPLATFORM_lapack -L/home/david/my_project/itensor/lib -litensor -lpthread -L/usr/lib -lblas -llapack")

#Append the new flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 ${ITENSOR_FLAGS}")

add_executable(my_project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_project itensor "${ITENSOR_LINK_FLAGS}")
```

**Motivation**: In the folder `itensor/project_template` there is a sample program which is simple enough to compile with `make` (from the terminal). The output of the compilation reveals the flags:

```
g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -c -I. -I/home/david/my_project/itensor -I/usr/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -DPLATFORM_lapack -D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0 -Wno-unused-variable -o myappname.o myappname.cc

[... some warnings ...]

g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -c -I. -I/home/david/my_project/itensor -I/usr/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -DPLATFORM_lapack -D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0 -Wno-unused-variable -o myclass.o myclass.cc
g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -I. -I/home/david/my_project/itensor -I/usr/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -DPLATFORM_lapack -D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0 -Wno-unused-variable myappname.o myclass.o -o myappname -L/home/david/my_project/itensor/lib -litensor -lpthread -L/usr/lib -lblas -llapack
```

Comment: Nice one! That also removes my issues with Lapack !!

Answer (score 0):

I got around the issue with the following main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "itensor/itensor.h"

int main() {
    std::string some_string = "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

And the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(tutorial)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

#Bring the headers into the project
include_directories(/home/tom/Documents/workspace/ITensor/)

#Link the library
add_library(itensor STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET itensor PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/tom/Documents/workspace/ITensor/lib/libitensor.a)

set(SOURCE_FILES  main.cpp)
add_executable(tutorial ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Where the path to ITensor can be either relative (using the ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} variable) or absolute as I have shown.

Comment: Hi Thomas, great! Thanks for that quick reply! Now it seems to work (meaning I get another error, which however this time is linked to lapack so not concerning this post anymore :) ).

Just I think you swapped the "project(tutorial)" line from the CMakeLists.txt into the main.cpp (probably just while copy pasting into the post)?